# Is the Eclipse MicroProfile Metrics annotation @Timed thread safe on Payara?

Tags: java, thread-safety, metrics, payara, microprofile

Since the @Timed annotation did not work with my SOAP-based web service, I wrote a SOAP Handler to be able to measure the duration of a web service call myself. **I wonder if this solution is thread-safe.**

The source code of my SOAP Handler:

```
package nl.tent.laboratory.emp.metrics;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.metrics.MetricID;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.metrics.MetricRegistry;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.metrics.Timer;

/**
 * Deze klasse klokt de web service calls.
 *
 * Daar de Eclipse MicroProfile Metrics annotatie @Timed niet werkt in combinatie met de annotatie @WebService klokken we zelf.
 */
public class TimerSOAPHandler extends AbstractGenericSOAPHandler {

    @Inject
    MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    public TimerSOAPHandler() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        // Bij het inkomende bericht (request) wordt de tijdsmeting gestart.
        if (isInbound(context)) {
            startTiming(context);
        }
        // Bij het uitgaande bericht (response) wordt de tijdsmeting gestopt.
        if (isOutbound(context)) {
            stopTiming(context);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        // Bij het inkomende bericht (request) wordt de tijdsmeting gestart.
        if (isInbound(context)) {
            startTiming(context);
        }
        // Bij het uitgaande bericht (response) wordt de tijdsmeting gestopt.
        if (isOutbound(context)) {
            stopTiming(context);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void startTiming(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        String serviceName = ((QName) context.get(MessageContext.WSDL_SERVICE)).toString();
        String operationName = ((QName) context.get(MessageContext.WSDL_OPERATION)).getLocalPart();

        Timer timer = metricRegistry.timer(serviceName + "_" + operationName + "_timer");

        Timer.Context timerContext = timer.time(); // start
    }

    private void stopTiming(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        String serviceName = ((QName) context.get(MessageContext.WSDL_SERVICE)).toString();
        String operationName = ((QName) context.get(MessageContext.WSDL_OPERATION)).getLocalPart();

        MetricID metricID = new MetricID(serviceName + "_" + operationName + "_timer");

        Timer timer = metricRegistry.getTimers().get(metricID);

        Timer.Context timerContext = timer.time();
        timerContext.stop();
    }

}
```

In the meantime the @Timed annotation is working and I would prefer to use the @Timed annotation. **However, I wonder if this (@Timed) is thread safe.**

I use the Payara implementation of Eclipse MicroProfile Metrics.